# Laravel 8 Check which columns is affected by cascade delete

Tags: laravel, model, cascading-deletes

I have a Laravel 8 project and I must implement cascade delete on it. It's okay but i want to warn the user if he deletes something, then belonging items will be deleted too.
So i want to know if i delete a model (a row in the database), which other models (other tables/columns) affected by this deletion.
How can i achieve this function? Thanks!

Comment: Since the cascade delete is part of the structure, it should be "known" and not "to be detected". for example deleting a User will delete his Posts because that is how you structured it. You dont go check if it's the case in the database, you know there will be deleted posts.

Comment: Following on from @N69S's example, you would just have to return `$user->posts()` (or whichever models you've set up to delete and cascade) and show them in the UI, like "The following posts will be deleted if the user is deleted: ..."

Comment: If you need something more advanced, you can make a trait to use in models, take the trait `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes` as an example, it is exactly the same as your case, something in your structure is know to have soft delete, then use the trait.

Comment: Thank you both! My final solution is to examine the relations, expand the migration, and with that knowledge, expand the UI. @N69S if you post yout comment as an answer, i will accept as an answer

Comment: @JoeX thank you but there is no need as your question is opinion based => off topic :) Happy to help anyway